# 183 day rule in conjunction with expatriate

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a US citizen but have lived and worked n Germany for 4 years.  From Jan. 2013 - March 2014, I was working on a Project in the US as an expatriate.  I have taken some Business trips back to the US since March 2014.  Do I Need to worry about the 183 day rule?  Naturally, my Company is taking care of the taxes for 2013 & 2014 because I was an expatriate.  Will going over the 183 days be detrimental?

Comment: Are you sure you've gone over the 183 days? You count all of the days in 2014, but count only 1/3 of the days that you were present in the US in 2013 so if you made any trips out of the US that year, you might be able to squeak by.

Comment: @mkennedy what are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that the 183 rule doesn't count for citizens. For non-US citizens, here's the link to the IRS topic on ['substantial presence'](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Substantial-Presence-Test).

Answer (score 1):

There's no "183 days" rule. As a US citizen you must pay taxes on all your income, where you live is irrelevant.

Comment: German tax law has such a rule, so it might be relevant from that perspective.